# What is the icon on the new left nav?

Tags: discussion, left-navigation

The new left nav looks like:

[image]

What is the icon meant to refer to?

Would have expected something like:

[image]

Also at meta we have:

[image]

There's no heading but a "question" link. Why does this differ?

Comment: I don't think Teams have their own separate Meta sites so there's no need to differentiate between public and private on Meta.

Comment: @BSMP Well maybe - I'm not in teams so I don't know. But in any case it could be the same (i.e. logo + Stack Overflow Meta) - just without the TEAMS below.

Comment: @BSMP is correct. There is no meta side to Teams, so there's no need to differentiate between public and private sites.

Comment: This is really awful looking and disturbing!

Comment: It's a pretty terrible-looking icon. As some comments below say, a lock would probably be better (or nothing at all).

Comment: In fact the whole left panel is horrible, the top tabs were much better

Comment: That's a "Cracked Egg" symbol, to show how scrambled and broken...

Answer (score 14):

The globe probably refers to something like "open to the whole world", as-in public, as opposed to Teams, which are restricted to specific (paying) individuals.

Comment: Hmm... So it's a globe? I would never have associated like that. So it would be... part of north and south America?

Comment: @4386427:  It's not uncommon for places based around a specific part of the earth to have a globe shot of their predominant country.  In the Americas that'd be North and South America; in Japan it'd look like Japan surrounded by the rest of the Asian continent.

Comment: @Makoto I guess it's not uncommon but ... what a strange logo for an international site. Anyway - this is probably the correct answer but I'll wait a moment to see if further explanation pops up in another answer.

Comment: It probably should just go away...but that's a separate request.

Comment: This looks like a 'developer design decision' to me. I make them all the time in conjunction with Noun Project.

Comment: @McNab I would have used to lock icons - an open lock for the public SO, and a closed one for the private teams. But then again, I spend a sizable portion of my professional life with a command line, so maybe I shouldn't be giving UI advice.

Comment: an open lock would fit better. for teams, it could be a closed lock.

Comment: @Makoto FWIW as a European, my globe also seems to be centered on America.

Comment: ...or, it could be Africa and a part of South America!

Comment: @Soltius The globe is a stationary image. What I think Makoto meant is that the icon's creator was from the Americas, and thus drew the globe like that. Had he or she been European, it would probably look different.

Answer (score 11):

To add to @Mureinik's answer, the use of a globe to indicate (no) privacy is pretty well established.  Here's Facebook's post privacy menu:

[image]

In response to the suggestion of using a lock, that generally conveys "security", not privacy.  It may seem like semantics, but it's different.

Comment: I agree with you on the lock but I would quibble with your Facebook example. There Facebook is clearly explaining what the icon means. On Stackoverflow there is no context for their version of the icon and so it wasn't clear to me that it meant anything. The fact it's the only item in that section that has an icon doesn't help.

Comment: Facebook's reverse-colour globe is prettier, though.

Comment: A closed lock is typically used for private or secure (or a chained link for private link). But an Open lock is a fairly common icon for public so I don't know if I agree with you on the lock, if open, as showing security.