# Change the icon and improve the new left nav

Tags: feature-request

So we got a new page layout on SO - that is a left nav looking like:

[image]

This is a feature request to get some change to the current design.

> Number 1: Change the icon

[image]

The icon is apparently supposed to be a globe (see [What is the icon on the new left nav?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369480/what-is-the-logo-on-the-new-left-nav))

I don't understand why this icon should be good. As SO is an international site, I think it makes little sense to use a "globe" that is only common to (perhaps) one third of SO users, i.e. American users.

Further - why not use the SO logo that we all know, i.e.

[image]

> Number 2: Bring back the "questions" link

The new left nav has no "question link". I find that strange. How should anyone know that you have to press "icon - Stack Overflow" to get to the questions?

Please change it like:

[image]

so there is a specific link for questions (and an appropriate icon)

As a minor....

What is the purpose of "home"?

It shows a list of "Top Questions" for all tags. I would never use that as my "home".

Comment: I don't see how a globe is unrecognizable to anyone who doesn't live in the part of the globe that's visible.  You might think that that particular globe isn't distinctive enough because of its level of detail, or colorization, or resolution, or whatever, but the part of the globe facing you is just...not relevant.

Comment: @servy 1) The first part is to recognize that it's a globe. If you're are used to see a globe with (what I assume is) part of north and south America, it's probably easy for you. But many SO users ain't used to see the globe like that and may (like my self) wonder: what is that icon supposed to be. 2) What is it supposed to mean in the context of SO? To me there is no obvious association between "questions" and a "globe"

Comment: @4386427 I've see lots of globe icons in different contexts that were facing such that were I live wasn't shown.  That has never been a factor in whether or not the icon was clear.  And I honestly have to say that I've never seen someone say that seeing a globe was an indication that something *wasn't* international.  Globes are *often* used in iconography to indicate that something *is* international, or *global*, in scope (which is, in fact, what why it's being used here).

Comment: @Servy good for you that you can recognize a globe no matter which parts of the world it includes in a few pixels. I couldn't... which is why I like it changed.

Comment: If you don't think that that icon is clear, then by all means, say that you don't think that globe is particularly clear, whether you think it's too small, too low resolution, or whatever.  But *which part of the world it's facing*, isn't the issue here.

Comment: @Servy Exactly - the feature request is to replace it with the well known SO logo

Comment: @4386427 Which doesn't accomplish it's goal of differentiating which part of SO you're on.  *All* of the sections shown are a part of SO, not just the questions list.

Comment: @servy Are you referring to TEAMS versus public SO? Is that it? The globe is intended to show - you are now on the world-wide SO

Comment: Related: [Facebook’s Globe Is No Longer Americentric](http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2014/07/31/facebook_notifications_icon_globe_changes_with_location_as_american_users.html)

Comment: My interpretation: The icon is supposed to indicate that you're dealing with the public (global) portion of the SO site, as opposed to a Team, which can have their own logos. The differentiation is much more clear when you are a member of a Team, or Teams.

Comment: @Servy and Op - Reason for the globe is more due to the integration on teams.  Seeing the globe means you are on the PUBLIC site and posting publicly.  Otherwise you are on a PRIVATE site - the team.  It makes sense yes...do we need it I think not...to me no image is necessary for this.  Simply have it say Stackoverflow.

Comment: Personally I think the globe icon is secondary to the bigger issue that this menu item goes to `/questions` with no apparent reason based on the menu item name. I would rename it "Questions", or I would remove the link on it and just make it a header, and add a new menu item below it called "Questions"

Comment: @user2285236 I was just about to recommend that SO could follow Facebook's method and show a globe centered on the continent of origin for the user. I didn't realize it was a thing until I went overseas to Germany back in 2016 and logged into Facebook and the globe icon centered on Europe. A tiny thing, but it was very neat to see!

Answer (score 46):

Can we have no icon at all?  As a third option?  I don't see the improvement with your suggestion of an icon and it's only exacerbating the actual issue:  **no icon required**.

Comment: Well, I don't disagree.... no icon would be better than the current.

Comment: IIRC the icon was to emphasize that it's going to public Stack Overflow instead just the team you're in.  Irrelevant for a majority of users, but that's why the icon was there.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's still a real bad introduction of TEAMS. That is - since we do TEAMS, all regulars have to accept a bad design :-(

Comment: No icon is required but if it is removed it will lead to further confusion about why there is an SO link and a Home link right above it when really there should just be one link and /questions & home should both present the same view/list.

Comment: @TylerH: Given the nature of teams, there is no guarantee that one link will ever be suitable. What about accounts on other teams? Seems simplest to be to have the icon on team channels instead of public.

Comment: @Makoto I don't mean Teams, I mean "Home" and "Questions". There shouldn't be a "questions" link because there shouldn't even be a "questions" page. All the questions and filter/sort functionality should just be there on the home page.